# How to load Sandbox.html in chrome extension MV 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a react app in content script which is attached to DOM via Shadow root. It uses manifest version 3.

I want to render `sandbox.html` in content script but chrome blocks it from displaying. I want to use sandbox.html to run media encoder logic to bypass csp warning.
Here is the error message:
[image]

`content script`

```
const MySandboxIframe = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="testR" id="theFrame">
        <iframe
          id="theFrame"
          src={chrome.runtime.getURL('sandbox.html')} //sandbox.html in public folder, It has a script loaded sandbox.js file
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100px',
          }}
          sandbox="allow-scripts"
        ></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`sandbox.html in public folder`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sandbox.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is hidden inside a hidden sandboxed iframe.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`sandbox.js in public folder`

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('=============> sandbox.js');
});
```

`manifest.json v3`

```
...
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
  }
...
```

How could I render the iframe without getting blocked by the browser? any idea?

Comment: It's unclear why you've used `sandbox` in manifest.json. To expose content use [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: I want to run javascript kinda ffmpeg in sandbox

Comment: If ffmpeg is JS you can run it without sandbox, otherwise you'll need to modify CSP to allow COEP headers. Anyway, use web_accessible_resources for the iframe's html in the web page, then you can add another sandboxed iframe inside if necessary.

Comment: I tried rendering html from `web_accessible_resources` , but chrome still blocks it. I inspected the error message it has a class="neterror". btw chrome manifest v3 doesn't allow `eval` in the extension, so it recommends to use sandbox

Comment: Assuming you declared it properly, don't forget to reload the extension. As for eval, if that library needs it then indeed you'll also need a sandbox. If I wasn't clear, you'll likely need two separate different htmls: one for the outer iframe inside the web page and another one for the inner sandbox.

Comment: do you have a link to an external website or something where I can see some code. I don't get it why I need two htmls, I am new to chrome extension field. I have another solution in my head, is it possible to send a postMessage to an iframe which loads a remote URL and I can run (`eval`) logic in iframe

Comment: There should be examples around, I don't have any links. The outer iframe is defined in web_accessible_resources and is added to the web page. This iframe creates another iframe inside, which is defined in `sandbox`. This inner iframe can use eval or external code. To communicate you would use the standard web cross-frame communication via iframeElem.contentWindow.postMessage.